# Opencart 3.0.2.0 How to set selected home page

Tags: layout, opencart, opencart-3

I have downloaded a opencart theme (Theme link -  https://elements.envato.com/wine-food-drink-theme-for-opencart-3-x-8VWE8Z)
Successfully installed it, but it shows default homepage
**I want to set home page 3 for my default store**

What I tried (and not worked)
1.Chanage layout in store settings
2.chage layout settings in design->layout
3.change layout in modules - this change the home page, but still shows styles from default home page .

How can I do this?

Comment: After you made some changes you must in ADMIN dashboard refresh extensions/modifications and clear the cache... blue gear icon in the right upper corner.

Comment: already tried.. Nothing happens

Comment: Is this is the correct way to change the home page?

Comment: Clear browser cache also. If theme are regarding OC standard it should work. Different themes are set in different ways. You should check in system/setting and if you find there new theme change it to the new. Maybe this theme must be enabled via extensions/extension/modules, or extensions/extension/themes... so check it.

Comment: Thank you. Finally it worked. I changed extension/theme -> store 1 -> theme directory

Comment: if my suggestion was useful, you can mark it as useful.

Comment: @K.B.it was useful. Thankyou

Comment: to mark as useful, just click grey/orange triangle...